Java Snake Game randomly starts showGameOverDialog
Have been working on this the whole day, learning as i go. Its my first somewhat complex piece of code.
Its a simple Snake game with highscores and a somewhat working menu. been watching tutorials the whole day and putting this together.
The game has a problem with the showGameOverDialog, with seemingly randomly starts no matter what tha game currently does, even in the menu and also when collecting an apple (lol).
i know its not really anythink important, but can anyone help me out with this one?
kinda want this to be my little hobbythingy and have lots of ideas to extend it with.
Thanks in advance :)
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SnakeGame extends JFrame {

    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private MainMenuPanel mainMenuPanel;
    private HighScorePanel highScorePanel;
    private OptionsPanel optionsPanel;
    private boolean fullscreen = false;

    public SnakeGame() {
        setTitle("Snake Game");
        setSize(800, 800);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

        gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
        mainMenuPanel = new MainMenuPanel(this);
        highScorePanel = new HighScorePanel(this);
        optionsPanel = new OptionsPanel(this);

        mainPanel.add(mainMenuPanel, "MainMenu");
        mainPanel.add(gamePanel, "Game");
        mainPanel.add(highScorePanel, "HighScores");
        mainPanel.add(optionsPanel, "Options");

        add(mainPanel);
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "MainMenu");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void showCard(String card) {
        cardLayout.show(mainPanel, card);
    }

    public void toggleFullscreen() {
        dispose();
        if (fullscreen) {
            setUndecorated(false);
            setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            setSize(800, 800);
        } else {
            setUndecorated(true);
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        }
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SnakeGame();
    }
}

class MainMenuPanel extends JPanel {

    public MainMenuPanel(SnakeGame frame) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Spiel starten");
        JButton highScoreButton = new JButton("Highscores");
        JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Optionen");
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Spiel beenden");

        startButton.addActionListener(e -> frame.showCard("Game"));
        highScoreButton.addActionListener(e -> frame.showCard("HighScores"));
        optionsButton.addActionListener(e -> frame.showCard("Options"));
        exitButton.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

        add(startButton);
        add(highScoreButton);
        add(optionsButton);
        add(exitButton);
    }
}

class OptionsPanel extends JPanel {

    public OptionsPanel(SnakeGame frame) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        JButton toggleFullscreenButton = new JButton("Vollbild / Fenster");
        JButton backButton = new JButton("Zurück zum Hauptmenü");

        toggleFullscreenButton.addActionListener(e -> frame.toggleFullscreen());
        backButton.addActionListener(e -> frame.showCard("MainMenu"));

        add(toggleFullscreenButton);
        add(backButton);
    }
}

class HighScorePanel extends JPanel {

    private SnakeGame frame;
    private JTextArea highScoreArea;
    private static final String HIGHSCORE_FILE = "highscore.txt";

    public HighScorePanel(SnakeGame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        highScoreArea = new JTextArea();
        highScoreArea.setEditable(false);

        JButton backButton = new JButton("Zurück zum Hauptmenü");
        backButton.addActionListener(e -> frame.showCard("MainMenu"));

        add(new JScrollPane(highScoreArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(backButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        loadHighScores();
    }

    private void loadHighScores() {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(HIGHSCORE_FILE))) {
            highScoreArea.read(reader, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            highScoreArea.setText("Keine Highscores gefunden.");
        }
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final int TILE_SIZE = 25;
    private static final int BOARD_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 30;
    private static final int DELAY = 140;
    private static final String HIGHSCORE_FILE = "highscore.txt";

    private final List<Point> snake = new ArrayList<>();
    private Point food;
    private char direction = 'R';
    private Timer timer;
    private int score = 0;
    private int highScore = 0;
    private SnakeGame frame;

    public GamePanel(SnakeGame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TILE_SIZE * BOARD_WIDTH, TILE_SIZE * BOARD_HEIGHT));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        loadHighScore();
        initGame();
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int key = e.getKeyCode();
                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && direction != 'R') {
                    direction = 'L';
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && direction != 'L') {
                    direction = 'R';
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && direction != 'D') {
                    direction = 'U';
                } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && direction != 'U') {
                    direction = 'D';
                }
            }
        });
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void loadHighScore() {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(HIGHSCORE_FILE))) {
            highScore = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            highScore = 0;
        }
    }

    private void saveHighScore() {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(HIGHSCORE_FILE))) {
            writer.write(String.valueOf(highScore));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initGame() {
        snake.clear();
        snake.add(new Point(5, 5));
        snake.add(new Point(4, 5));
        snake.add(new Point(3, 5));
        score = 0;
        placeFood();
    }

    private void placeFood() {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * BOARD_WIDTH);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * BOARD_HEIGHT);
        food = new Point(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawBoard(g);
        drawSnake(g);
        drawFood(g);
        drawScore(g);
    }

    private void drawBoard(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; y++) {
                g.drawRect(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawSnake(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Point point : snake) {
            g.fillRect(point.x * TILE_SIZE, point.y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
        }
    }

    private void drawFood(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillRect(food.x * TILE_SIZE, food.y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
    }

    private void drawScore(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g.drawString("Score: " + score, 10, getHeight() - 10);
        g.drawString("Highscore: " + highScore, 10, getHeight() - 40);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        moveSnake();
        checkCollision();
        repaint();
    }

    private void moveSnake() {
        Point head = new Point(snake.get(0));
        switch (direction) {
            case 'L':
                head.x--;
                break;
            case 'R':
                head.x++;
                break;
            case 'U':
                head.y--;
                break;
            case 'D':
                head.y++;
                break;
        }
        snake.add(0, head);
        snake.remove(snake.size() - 1);
    }

    private void checkCollision() {
        Point head = snake.get(0);
        if (head.equals(food)) {
            snake.add(food);
            placeFood();
            score++;
            if (score > highScore) {
                highScore = score;
                saveHighScore();
            }
        }

        if (head.x < 0 || head.x >= BOARD_WIDTH || head.y < 0 || head.y >= BOARD_HEIGHT) {
            timer.stop();
            showGameOverDialog();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            if (head.equals(snake.get(i))) {
                timer.stop();
                showGameOverDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    private void showGameOverDialog() {
        String message = String.format("Game Over\nScore: %d\nHighscore: %d", score, highScore);
        int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, message, "Game Over", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Zurück zum Hauptmenü", "Spiel beenden"}, "Zurück zum Hauptmenü");
        if (option == 0) {
            frame.showCard("MainMenu");
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        initGame();
        timer.start();
    }
}

Tried to play around with the code related to the showGameOverDialog, havent been able to figure something out.

When you put debugging breakpoints on the calls to showGameOverDialog(), which is triggered unexpectedly?  When that happens, what are the values being compared in the if statement that triggers it?  Of those values, which isn't what you expected?  Where did you get that value and why did you expect a different one?

actionPerformed (and thus checkCollision) gets called whether a game is in progress or not.

In your GamePanel class, you initialize direction:
private char direction = 'R';

And the constructor of that same class immediately starts its Timer, the moment the GamePanel is created:
timer.start();

Which means that the instant the GamePanel is created—not when the user starts a game—the snake is already moving rightward, regardless of whether the user can see it happening.  When the snake collides with the right edge, the game is over.
The solution involves two steps:

Remove timer.start(); from the constructor.
Call timer.start(); when the user presses the start button:  startButton.addActionListener(e -> { frame.showCard("Game"); timer.start(); });

